# How to clean and reset Ubuntu partitions and GRUB menu

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted, grub-efi

I'm quite new to Linux and I think I accidentally removed files related to my boot configurations while clearing redundant disk on my secondary SSD. After that my computer was unable to detect any bootable partitions. Since then, I've managed to recover the files I need by installing another Ubuntu distribution from live USB but now there are two boot options in GRUB and I only want one.

My partition setup is quite messy now and I'm not sure which ones are safe to delete. But I know the only partitions that definitely need to be kept are `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and `/dev/nvme0n1p2` which are mounted to `/` and `/home` respectively.

[image: Screenshot of partition from GParted]

Is there a nice way to fix this? What should my partitions look like ideally? I am only using Ubuntu 18.04 and do not need to dual boot or anything fancy.

Edit:
I've tried to use the advanced options in boot-repair and this is the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vFzjzVQtfv/.

Comment: Use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair "What should my partitions look like ideally? " That is for you to decide. It largely depends on how you use your system. I have a /discworld/ with all my personal data that I re-use across different Linux systems (I have Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04 and Fedora, CentOS and Debian due to clients using those and me supporting them ;-)

Comment: I've used it with the recommended repair, but it didn't help. Do you have recommendations on what advanced settings I should use?

Comment: Sorry no :-) you will need to wait for someone else to answer this :)

Comment: You can ignore errors on mount of p4. If Boot-Repair does not recognized partition it tries to mount as NTFS. But your p4 is from a BIOS install of Ubuntu and is a bios_grub partition. Because it is unformatted many tools do not see it correctly. But you also have an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. Back up all your data, /home, list of installed apps and any system changes in /etc you made. New install in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drive will be just an ESP & /. If you use Something Else you can also add /home. I now use 30GB for / if all data in either /home or data partition(s).

Comment: So to clarify, should I be removing everything except for p1 and p2 then installing ubuntu again from live USB? Or should I also leave p5 in? Because I think the reason I added p4 before was because the boot-repair didn't work without a bios_grub flag, and GParted complained without a boot/esp flag.